# Subclassing an array in JavaScript ES5

Tags: javascript

In ES5, the naive way (yes, I know about the `length` issues) to subclass an array was [as follows](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/):

```js
function MyArray() {
  [].push.apply(this, arguments)
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)

const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
console.log(arr)
```

In the constructor function, how did people know to call `push` instead of calling the `Array` constructor against the subclass (which does not work)?

```js
function MyArray() {
  Array.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Is this intuitive, or documented, or something that would have had to have been found by trial and error?

Comment: If you call it by intuition/trail'n'error/observation depends on what the one _"inventing"_ this did know about JavaScript at that time. At some point, it was known that due to the way how JavaScript evolved, inheriting from or extending certain types is buggy/problematic. So it would have been at least expected that calling the Array constructor would likely not work. And from that point, it would have been some educated guesses on how to solve the problem, with some tests if it works cross-browser (not sure if that should be called trial and error)

Comment: I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `[].push.apply(this, arguments)` is equivalent to calling `this.push(...arguments)`. So while it might look like you're pushing the arguments onto an empty array, you're actually pushing them onto "your self" since you "extend" the array prototype `MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)` and therefor implements the "push" function.

```js
function MyArray() {
  this.push(...arguments)
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)

const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
console.log(arr)
```

If you instead were to call `Array.apply(this, arguments)` you're actually creating a new array instance containing "arguments", instead of mutating "your self".

```js
function MyArray() {
  const arr = Array.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log('inner', arr);
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)

const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
console.log('outer', arr)
```

Edit1:

> Lets consider the normal case of const arr = Array(). In this case the value of this inside the Array function would be the global object. However we don't need anything from the global object in order to create a new instance of Array, so no methods (or variables) are accessed using this. In other words, the Array function will always produce a new instance, in the same way no matter what the value of this happens to be. (Implementation wise the Array function is actually native code, so this analogy only works in theory)

We can show this by passing in a proxy as the `this` argument, and logging all interactions with it:

```js
const loggingProxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get(__, key) {
    console.log('get', key);
    return __[key];
  },
  set(__, key, value) {
    console.log('set', key, value);
    __[key] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

const arr = Array.apply(loggingProxy, [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(arr);
```

As you can see, no "get" or "set" is logged, hence the `Array` function is not accessing anything on the `this` reference.

Comment: That does not really answer the question of the OP. Which is not about what `[].push.apply(this, arguments)` does any why `Array.apply(this, arguments)` does not work. But how someone came to the conclusion about how to solve the problem of inheriting from `Array` in this way.

Comment: It does answer the question. Seeing as you need to understand how & why the solution works in order to be able to reason about how the solution came to be in the first place.

Comment: @Olian04 OK, so if calling `Array.apply(this, arguments)` creates a new `Array` instance and does not call it against `this`, why does the `Array` constructor function do this? Is it simply a quirk?

Comment: @52d6c6af I'm not quite sure i follow. `Array` is a function, and every function in javascript implements the `apply` method. The `apply` method requires a `thisArg` as its first argument. However since the purpose of the `Array` function is to create a new instance of Array, it wont use the `thisArg` of apply during the construction of the new instance.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't use `this` during construction, is there? `function Ctor() { this.foo = 'foo!' } const o = new Ctor(); o.foo // foo!`

Comment: @52d6c6af Lets consider the normal case of `const arr = Array()`. In this case the value of `this` inside the Array function would be the global object. However we don't need anything from the global object in order to create a new instance of Array, so no methods (or variables) are accessed using `this`. In other words, the  Array function will always produce a new instance, in the same way no matter what the value of `this` happens to be. (Implementation wise the `Array` function is actually native code, so this analogy only works in theory).

Comment: OK, so is the answer that `Array` was written in order that `new` need not be used?

Comment: Well but `If you instead were to call Array.apply(this, arguments) you're actually creating a new array instance containing "arguments", instead of mutating "your self".` is not really what you would expect from in a normal situation in JS, this is just because `Array` works differently and does not require the `new` keyword to be constructed and in retrospect, this was a bad decision.

Comment: Don't "all" the intrinsic objects behave in this way? `Object() // {}`, `Number(1) // 1` etc.

Comment: @52d6c6af That is certainly one way of phrasing it. And as @t.niese said, not requiring the `new` keyword might have been a mistake when designing the Array function.